# Performance of c# FileStream.Seek vs FileStream.ReadBytes. Why is the latter faster?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, filestream

In my application I need to frequently move the position pointer of a file stream forward a small number of bytes. Experimentation with using FileStream.ReadBytes rather than FileStream.Seek for this purpose revealed that the former was significantly faster than the latter.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
    static void OptimizedSeek(Stream theStream, long offset)
    {
        if (offset!= 0)
        {
            if (offset> 0 && offset< 4096)
            {
                theStream.Read(new byte[offset], 0, (int)offset);
            }
            else
            {
                theStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputFile = "datafile.dat";

        FileStream myStream = new FileStream(inputFile,FileMode.Open);            

        Random r = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(myStream.Position);
        var maxLength = myStream.Length;
        int delta = r.Next(0, 1000);
        long pos = delta;
       
        while (pos < maxLength)
        {
            //myStream.Seek(delta, SeekOrigin.Current);
            OptimizedSeek(myStream, delta);
            delta = r.Next(0, 1000);
            pos += delta;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myStream.Position);

    }
```

If I instead use myStream.Seek(delta, SeekOrigin.Current) instead of OptimizedSeek, performance is significantly worse (10 time on my system). datafile.dat is here around 800mb.

Anyone with knowledge as to why I see this difference in performance? At the outset I would expect Seek to be optimized for this exact purpose.

I'm using .net5 and compiling for Windows.

Comment: Which .NET version? This smells like the `Seek` might be discarding the read buffer, but the latest .NET does this properly.

Comment: .net 5 @canton7

Comment: And what plattform then. We are talking about something that is plattform dependent

Comment: @Ralf the platform is windows

Comment: I *think* you're hitting either the `else if` or the `else` case [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cf258a14b70ad9069470a108f13765e0e5988f51/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/FileStream.Windows.cs#L566) (I don't see how the `if` case can be hit, because `_readPos` and `_readLength` are set to 0 above). One of those involves a buffer copy and a p/invoke to `SetFilePointerEx`, and the other discards the read buffer entirely. On the other hand, a normal `Read` will just read from the read buffer, and often won't encounter a p/invoke.

Comment: The latest .NET on the other hand [seems to handle this better](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs,918) from what I can gather, so you might find that the performance of `Seek` is better in your test on .NET 6.

Comment: .NET 5 goes end-of-life this coming Sunday, so it's time to upgrade anyway!

Comment: @canton7 yes! The difference between net5 and net6 is profound. With net5 the example takes ~3 minutes, while with net6 it runs in less than 3 seconds. (using .Seek). Wow.

Comment: Impressive, that's a much larger difference than I was expecting! `FileStream` was [entirely rewritten for speed in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/file-io-improvements-in-dotnet-6/). It looks like that article talks about `Seek` performance in particular -- I should have re-read it sooner...

Comment: I would say its both. But since @Jens benchmarked/compared it the problem seems to be  the frameworks implementation in this case.